# How do I use sqlalchemy to dump to a .sql file?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've got some python code that runs ~15 `select` queries use `sqlalchemy` and gets the data. I'd like to dump all of these into a single `.sql` file so that I can later load this into a MySQL databae. I can't find any docs on how to do this.

Comment: A first approximation would be to set `engine.echo = True`, send logging output to a file, and run the Python code.

Comment: The best answer depends on what those 15 select queries are. If they are simple queries against one table each, with no expressions, then I'd use `mysqldump`, optionally with `--where`. That way I wouldn't have to figure out how to format the results into valid SQL syntax.